# Firestore collection link

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a DB on firestore where there is a collection of 'Shops'. In these shops, they each have a document 'coupon' (limited to 1 per user).

How do i link the 'coupon' which is unique to each users in 'Shops' so that when User_1 uses his coupon, only User_1's coupon will be counted as 'used' and User_2's 'coupon' will not be used. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to store the unique ID of the coupon (maybe its document ID, or maybe a unique identifier generated by some other means) in a document belonging to the user so that you can simply add or remove coupon IDs to that users document.

For example, you might have a structure like `users/{user ID}` that has a document storing an array of coupon IDs. When a user uses a coupon, it can fetch that coupons information from `coupons/{coupon ID}` or `shops/{shop ID}/coupons/{coupon ID}`, then simply remove the coupon ID from the user's array, thus invalidating their coupon without invalidating the coupon's data for any other users with the same coupon.